# Directing IntelliJ to sources when debugging an external application

Tags: java, debugging, jmx

Say you have the source of an application, and you're debugging the jar via JMX. How do you tell IntelliJ where the source is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need a Java module in your project the references the sources (and I suspect the classes) and then run a remote debug session against your server.

Comment: So there's no way to do this without adding a java module?

Comment: This is how I've always done it because it's been my code I've been debugging and so I've had a module anyway.  You could play with setting up a project library and include the source there.